# installing lxml in python34 on amazon ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, lxml

I have seen many threads on this topic but I still can't get the lxml module installed in python34 on Amazon EC2.

I have installed the requests module with

```
sudo easy_install-3.4 requests
```

But if I try installing the lxml module with

```
sudo easy_install-3.4 lxml
```

It fails and I get

```
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.6.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/1b/fe6904151b37a0d6da6e60c13583945f8ce3eae8ebd0ec763ce546358947/lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz#md5=5957cc384bd6e83934be35c057ec03b6
Processing lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-i92lmsc5/lxml-3.6.0/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.6.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-i92lmsc5/lxml-3.6.0/egg-dist-tmp-km_e4sdc
Building lxml version 3.6.0.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So then I try to install libxml2 with:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel
```

And I get

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                   | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.2.50.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.12.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python26-devel-2.6.9-2.84.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So if the libxml2 module is already installed where is the problem please?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the following error message, it does not look like you have a compiler installed.

```
/usr/lib64 unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
```

You need to install a compiler as well, in addition to the development libraries.

```
sudo yum install gcc libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel
sudo easy_install-3.4 lxml
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was the problem.

Comment: Great! I would recommend that you add the [python] tag to your question as this was python related and accept this as the answer!